# use cmake to build klee

Tags: cmake, c++14, klee

I'm newer in using Linux and cmake.
I have some trouble when I want to build a KLEE system in ubuntu14.04.
When I come to the 8th part as the official page said. see in this page: http://klee.github.io/build-llvm34/

There is something wrong with the standard of c++ it uses -std=14 but I don't know why my compiler doesn't support it.

So my question is that: 1. is it necessary to use C++ 14? 2. and if is not how can I change the version the compiler used to avoid this kind of error?

llvm is 3.4
clang is 3.4

```
/home/codefiring/Desktop/software/klee/klee/tools/klee/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**, char**)’:
/home/codefiring/Desktop/software/klee/klee/tools/klee/main.cpp:1352:18: error: ‘put_time’ is not a member of ‘std’
               << std::put_time(std::localtime(&startTime), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") << '\n';
                  ^
/home/codefiring/Desktop/software/klee/klee/tools/klee/main.cpp:1460:16: error: ‘put_time’ is not a member of ‘std’
             << std::put_time(std::localtime(&endTime), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") << '\n'
                ^
make[2]: *** [tools/klee/CMakeFiles/klee.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [tools/klee/CMakeFiles/klee.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I remember successfully installing KLEE on Ubuntu 14.04 before ... can you please post the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: I change the question can you look for further?